# How to move bodies with no sliding in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

I am trying to create 2 boxes where 1 box `B` moves down and hits the other box `A`. I want `B` to move at constant speed (so I set its friction to 0 and stop it after a while). But I'm stuck on how to set `A`. I want `A` to get pushed and move out of `B`'s way, but also at constant speed and with no sliding. Which means `A` gets pushed until `B` is not pushing `A` anymore, which at that point `A` is not sliding/moving/rotating.

Anyone know how to fix it?

```js
   // module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Composite = Matter.Composite;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

engine.world.gravity.y = 0;

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 32, 32);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(425, 50, 32, 32);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });


console.log(boxA.friction, boxA.frictionAir, boxA.restitution);
boxA.friction = 0.75;
//boxA.frictionAir = 1;
boxA.restitution = 0.01;

boxB.friction = 0;
boxB.frictionAir = 0;
boxB.restitution = 0;

var x=425,y=50;
setTimeout(() => {
    Body.applyForce(boxB, boxB.position, {
        x: 0,
        y: 0.01
    });
    console.log("moving");
}, 1000);
setInterval(() => {
    Body.setAngularVelocity(boxB, 0);
    Body.setVelocity(boxB, {x: 0, y:0});
}, 3000);


// add all of the bodies to the world
Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();

// run the engine
Runner.run(runner, engine);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-5T245ZTH0m0RfONiFm2NF0zcYcmAuNzcGyPSQ18j8Bs5Pbfhp5HP1hosrR8XRt5M3kSRqzjNMYpm2+it/AUX/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```